# How to sum (instead of appending on a for-loop ) appended values in the defaultdict(list)?

Tags: python, for-loop, append, list-comprehension, defaultdict

In a defaultdict(list) type data. I used

```
for line in my_data:
    aln_counts = .... do something
    unique_Counts[transcript].append(aln_counts) # to append the data in a for-loop
# Output:
  defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'AL2G41400.t1_My': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'AL2G20730.t1_Sp': [4, 4]
```

Instead of appending I want the sum of the values in each for-loop; something like.

```
  defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'AL2G41400.t1_My': [12], 'AL2G20730.t1_Sp': [8]
```

Comment: why do you need a list at all, then? Just use `defaultdict(int)` and instead of `.append` use `unique_Counts[transcript] += 1`. Better yet, just use a `Counter`

Comment: Well, this code is part of my pipeline. I want to sum along the for-loop (when reading the lines) instead of appending.

Comment: That's not a reason to use a `defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Read the edits I made to my comment. using `defaultdict(list)` doesn'tmake any sense. Why do you want a `dict` of lists where each list has a single element, a number, which represents counts? Either use `defaultdict(int)` or simply use `collections.Counter`

Comment: But, I am not tyring to sum 1 to it. but what ever values comes out in the forloop.

Comment: @everestial007 ... then use that value instead of `1`... `unique_Counts['transcript'] += aln_counts`. Or better yet, **use a `Counter`**

Comment: ok, got it. Thanks much !